# can i use terraform to manage newly released AWS ECS autoscaling?

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, autoscaling, terraform-provider-aws

AWS just released support for AWS ECS autoscaling where autoscaling is performed natively by ECS managed service. Does terraform have support for this as the announcement just came in few days ago December 3rd, 2019 and today is December 8th.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-ecs-cluster-auto-scaling-is-now-generally-available/
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/12/amazon-ecs-cluster-auto-scaling-now-available/

Comment: Work has begun. https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/11151

Comment: very nice..thanks for this